# Facebook Marketing API, Hourly breakdown

Tags: facebook, api

I am extracting Ad Insights. I am using Facebook Marketing API.

I want to extract Spend & Offsite Conversions.
So following are the details:
**fields:** account_id, account_name, campaign_id, campaign_name, adset_id, adset_name, spend, actions

**Breakdowns:** hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone

**actions_breakdown:** action_type

Does anyone knows how facebook returns data? I mean how the data is returned by audience time zone at hourly basis by using above breakdown. You can refer to following sample response.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "impressions": "1148",
      "date_start": "2016-03-05",
      "date_stop": "2016-04-01",
      "hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone": "00:00:00 - 00:59:59"
    },
    {
      "impressions": "172",
      "date_start": "2016-03-05",
      "date_stop": "2016-04-01",
      "hourly_stats_aggregated_by_audience_time_zone": "01:00:00 - 01:59:59"
    }],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MjMZD"
    }
  }
}
```

If my ad is targeted in multiple regions(diff timezones) then how the data will be returned?

I don't have any timezone information to know which local timezone this data is aggregated.
Any help would be appreciated. Let me know my assumption about any term related to Facebook Marketing is incorrect.

Comment: _“Does anyone knows how facebook returns data?”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns/v2.9#hourlybreakdowns, “Show Response”

Answer (score 0):

The response format, as CBroe pointed out, is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns/v2.9#hourlybreakdowns

The data aggregation is based on audience's local time. If people are in different timezones, they all use their own local time for aggregation. (i.e. This can used to learn whether your ads are more effective during morning time or evening time.)

Comment: Could you be more elaborate on the point that data is aggregated by audience's local time zone. Could you please explain from the perspective of the developer who is making api call in his application. He may not know about the targeting set by the advertiser before making api call. The developer can simply see the response of kind I have added in question. Thanks.